# Removing all <tr> from a page using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with multiple `<tr>`. Some of them has set class on them.

I have `<tr>` with no class, with `class="Failure"` and with `class="Error"` (it's a JUnit html report).

I want to put a button on the page and after click on it to remove all tr with the defined class on them (Failure and Error).

I have tryed something like this:

```
$("tr").remove(":contains('Failure')");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean with class `Failure` *or* `Error`, do this:

```
$("tr.Failure,tr.Error").remove();   // remove those with either
```

If you mean with both classes:

```
$("tr.Failure.Error").remove();   // remove those with both
```

For both of these, you can move the selector to the `.remove()` as you had it:

```
$("tr").remove(".Failure,.Error");  // remove those with either
```

or:

```
$("tr").remove(".Failure.Error");  // remove those with both
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's a great answer ... but I want the oposite. I want to remove the <tr> with no class defined. My mistake posting the wrong problem

Comment: tinti - If you want to select those <tr> elements with no class attribute defined, you can use :not from JQuery. For example: $('tr:not([class])') .That will give you the tr nodes with no class attribute defined. You can then use remove() in various ways to remove the element(s) from the DOM

Comment: @tinti: What @Javier said is right. But to be clear, do you want those without *any* class, or just those without the "Error" and "Failure" classes?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery makes selecting elements by a class name very easy with `element.class-name` syntax. Just select the `<tr>` elements with the class you want, and remove them:

```
$('tr.Failure,tr.Error').remove();
```

The `:contains` selector doesn't match class names, only the text within the element.

Suggest you read up on your [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 1):

Should look like:

```
$('tr.Failure, tr.Error').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

These guys are correct dude, if you wanted it with a button:

```
$('.button-class').click(function() {
    $('tr.Failure, tr.Error').remove();
    return false;
});
```

Also if you wanted to remove the ones without a class:

```
$('.button-class').click(function() {
    $('tr').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('Error') || $(this).hasClass('Failure'))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
('.button-class').click(function() 
{
 $('tr').each(function() 
 { 
  if(!$(this).is('.Failure,.Error'))
     $(this).remove();
 });
});
```